# JSON.serialize: is it possible to suppress null values of a map?

Tags: apex, json, null, serialize

I tried to serialize a map with null value (api 45):

```
Map<String, String> bodyMap = new Map<String, String> {'key'=>'value', 'key2'=>null};
System.debug(JSON.serialize(bodyMap,true));
```

but it does not suppress null value (as it does in a custom object):

```
{"key2":null,"key":"value"}
```

Does it work as expected? Is there any other way than writing custom serialiser?

Comment: I don't believe that there is a way other than a custom serializer that you can use. Out the box JSON methods will take what they have an serialize it as is . With a custom serializer you will have the option of supplying a replacement for a null value.

Comment: This method `serialize(objectToSerialize, suppressApexObjectNulls)
` seems to work specifically on Apex `Object` types only and that the platform considers a Collection to be distinct from an Apex Object.

Comment: @JayantDas True. Same behaviour with List.

Comment: @kvor Even though it does not clearly calls out, but going through few references it does establish this distinction, I have added details as answer, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`JSON.serialize(objectToSerialize, suppressApexObjectNulls)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm?search_text=json)
mentions the type of `objectToSerialize` parameter as:

> Type: Object
>
> The Apex object to serialize.

And if you refer to other documentations (mentioned below), a Collection is always categorized differently than an Apex Object. Apex Object always refers to instances of custom/system classes within the platform.

So the behavior what you are experiencing is expected. Your option is to either go with a custom class or serialize only after removing the `null` values from the collection.

---

References for data types in Apex which mentions Collection differently than Apex Objects:

- [Data Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_data_types.htm)
- [Expressions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_understanding.htm)

Answer (score 8):

Yep, that's the expected behavior.

For simple maps, you can get rid of null values by iterating over the map keys, keeping track of which ones have null values, and then a little map manipulation.

```
Set<String> mapKeysToRemoveSet = new Set<String>();

for(String key :myMap.keySet()){
    if(myMap.get(key) == null){
        mapKeysToRemoveSet.add(key);
    }
}

// The Map class only comes with a remove() method, which only removes one item from the
//   map at a time.
// It's not a great idea to modify a collection while you're iterating over it.
// The solution is to get the map's keyset, then use the set class's removeAll() method.
// This has the effect of removing multiple items from the map in one shot.
myMap.keySet().removeAll(mapKeysToRemoveSet);

System.debug(JSON.serialize(myMap));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem which I had faced, and I came across a string manipulation method that strips out nulls from null json keys.

```
  public static string stripJsonNulls(string JsonString)
{

    if(JsonString != null)
    {
        JsonString = JsonString.replaceAll('\"[^\"]*\":null',''); //basic removeal of null values
        JsonString = JsonString.replaceAll(',{2,}', ','); //remove duplicate/multiple commas
        JsonString = JsonString.replace('{,', '{'); //prevent opening brace from having a comma after it
        JsonString = JsonString.replace(',}', '}'); //prevent closing brace from having a comma before it
        JsonString = JsonString.replace('[,', '['); //prevent opening bracket from having a comma after it
        JsonString = JsonString.replace(',]', ']'); //prevent closing bracket from having a comma before it
    }

    return JsonString;
}


Map<String, String> bodyMap = new Map<String, String> {'key'=>'value', 'key2'=>null};
System.debug(stripJsonNulls(JSON.serialize(bodyMap,false)));
```

OP : `{"key":"value"}`

Src: https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/stripping-nulls-from-a-json-object-in-apex/

Comment: You want to trust a site called "I Write Crappy Code?"

Comment:  what's in the  name ~ Shakespeare

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks but I would avoid using String.replaceAll(). It will result to "Regex too Complicated" Limit, if stripJsonNulls() is called in a loop.